# JavaScript no sound in chrome / not counting down in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, audio, mp3

I created a simple timer that does not count down in IE. In Chrome it works but does not play sound.. Do you have any suggestions as to why does it happen? i use SharePoint content editor to embed the code. Thanks!

```html
<Script>
<audio id="audioshort" src="/sites/MTDT/HTML/SiteAssets/Shortbeep.mp3" preload="auto"></audio><script>
<audio id="audiolong" src="/sites/MTDT/HTML/SiteAssets/Longbeep.mp3" preload="auto"></audio><script>
</Script>

<Script>
ProgressCountdown(20, 'pageBeginCountdown', 'pageBeginCountdownText').then(value => alert(`Stream time has ended. Please move to another stream`));

function ProgressCountdown(timeleft, bar, text) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var countdownTimer = setInterval(() => {
      timeleft--;

      document.getElementById(bar).value = 20 - timeleft;
      document.getElementById(text).textContent = timeleft;

      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownTimer);
        resolve(true);
 location.reload();
      }
      if (timeleft == 5) {
        document.getElementById('audioshort').play();  
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
</Script>
<div class="row begin-countdown">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <h2>Stream time left</h2>
    <progress value="0" max="20" id="pageBeginCountdown"></progress>
    <p><centre><span id="pageBeginCountdownText">20 </span> minutes<centre></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I find syntax error like you have Script tag after each Audio tag. Also the '=>' is not supported in IE. If you check the console than there are promise related errors. I suggest you to add type="audio/mpeg" attribute in your audio tag. Try to make a test in local browser than try to embed it using SharePoint content editor.

Answer (score 0):

You have some weird `Script` Tags around your audio files. It should read:

```html
<audio id="audioshort" src="/sites/MTDT/HTML/SiteAssets/Shortbeep.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<audio id="audiolong" src="/sites/MTDT/HTML/SiteAssets/Longbeep.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

That should solve the playback on Chrome.
For your issue with IE it depends which version you are using, but i guess that `Promise` is not supported. See https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises for more information.